# TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'send'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been working on an Express app and I just started getting a super weird error saying `TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'send'`. It started as I was trying to set up some routing for my app via the router provided by Express. I did some Googling and found that other people that were getting the `TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method __` (fill in the blank) were either not using Express, or they were doing something weird with the router. So, I created a new app file named `app-test.js` and trimmed out all of the extraneous code, including the router. However, I'm still getting the same error. Here's my setup now while I'm trying to figure out the problem:

**server.js**

```
var app = require("./app-test");

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 8000);

var server = app.listen(app.get("port"), function () {

var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port;

console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});

module.exports.app = app;
module.exports.server = server;
```

**app-test.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
path = require('path');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/testing', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I know that Express builds on Node.js's http's ServerResponse object. So, certain methods like `.end()` will still work even if Express isn't setup. However, the really weird thing about this problem is that Express's `.render()` method still works fine.

I'm completely stumped by this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've either messed with the express module or there is some kind of environmental issue because this works well for me.

Comment: Maybe just reinstall express and see what happens

Comment: Wow. That did the trick. I must have accidentally hit an Express file in a refactor. *Face-palm*. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this I ended up just reinstalling Express via `npm install` and it fixed the issue. I'm guessing that I hit a file during a refactor and didn't realize it.